# how to solve $\operatorname{rem}(6^{15},17)$ without using a calculator.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve $\operatorname{rem}(6^{15}, 17)$.

I know that we have to use congruences but don't know how to go on.

$6 ≅ 6 \mod 17$??

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Do I have to use CRT in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A low tech solution:

$6^2 = 36 \equiv 2 \pmod{17}$ ($34$ is a multiple of $17$).

So $6^4 = (6^2)^2 \equiv 2^2 = 4 \pmod{17}$

Hence: $6^8 = (6^4)^2 \equiv 4^2 = 16 \equiv -1 \pmod{17}$

Also: $6^{15}=6^1 \cdot 6^2 \cdot 6^4 \cdot 6^8$ ($15$ is $1111$ in binary), so modulo $17$ this becomes

$6 \times 2 \times 4 \times -1 = -48 \equiv -48 + 3\times 17 = 3$

So $3$ is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Recall that by [**Fermat's little theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

$$6^{16}\equiv 1 \mod 17$$

that is for some $k\in \mathbb Z$

$$6^{16}=k\cdot 17+1$$

Answer (score 1):

You need *lil' Fermat* and a Bézout's relation between $6$ and $17$, as
Fermat implies that $6^{15}\equiv 6^{-1}\mod 17$.

*Some more details*:

A Bézout's relation between $6$ and $17$ is obviously 
$\;3\cdot 6-17=1$, which implies $6^{-1}\equiv 3\bmod 17$.

Comment: i have not heard about this relation? could you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Great Bernard :o)....+1.

Comment: It is the relation which characterises coprime integers, and gives the inverse of an integer modulo the other. I'll add some details

Comment: so from both equation do you get 6^{15} ≡ 3 mod 17? is 3 the answer?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: thank you. i really appreciate it.